Insertar el id del pedido dentro de un mensaje enviado con PHPMailer
cuando el codigo recibe la información del mensaje me toma los datos de la tabla producto perfectamente pero en el area del mensaje necesito colocar el id del pedido y no se como hacer para que el id se coloque en el cuerpo despues de que registra el pedido y me envie ese mismo dato en el mensaje:
Creo el archivo:
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8mb4');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require '../vendor/autoload.php'; // Asegúrate de incluir el autoload 
de PHPMailer

// Obtener los datos del cuerpo de la solicitud
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$datos = json_decode($inputJSON, true);

require_once "../config/conexion.php";
require_once "../config/config.php";

Aqui en esta parte es donde necesito agregar el id del pedido: no del producto.
     $mensaje = "
    <html>
     <head>
    <charset=utf-8>
    <title>Pedido de productos</title>
    <body>
    <h2>Detalle del pedido (LISTA)</h2><br>

     **ID DEL PEDIDO <<<--------** <p><strong>ID del pedido:</strong> " . $nose['id'] . "</p>

    <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> " . $datos['nombre'] . "</p>
    <p><strong>Correo electrónico:</strong> " . $datos['correo'] . " 
     </p>
    <p><strong>Teléfono:</strong> " . $datos['telefono'] . "</p>
    <p><strong>Opción de entrega:</strong> " . $datos['tipoentrega'] . 
  "</p>
    <p><strong>Dirección de entrega:</strong> " . 
    $datos['direccionentrega'] . "</p>  

En este lugar es donde se registra el nuevo pedido en la tabla en si lo que necesito es que cuando se registre el nuevo pedido... el numero del id del nuevo pedido registrado me lo coloque en donde lo marque arriba...
// Enviar el correo electrónico
if ($mail->send()) {
//REGISTRAR PEDIDO
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['nombre']);
$correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['correo']);
$telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['telefono']);
$tipoentrega = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, 
$datos['tipoentrega']);
$direccionentrega = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, 
 $datos['direccionentrega']);
$productos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, 
json_encode($jsonProductos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

// Construir la consulta SQL escapando los valores


$query = "INSERT INTO pedidos (fecha, nombre, correo, telefono, 
 total, productos,tipoentrega, direccionentrega) VALUES ('$fecha', 
'$nombre', '$correo', '$telefono', '$total', '$productos', 
'$tipoentrega', '$direccionentrega')";

// Ejecutar la consulta SQL
if (mysqli_query($conexion, $query)) {
    $respuesta = array('success' => true, 'message' => '¡Pedido 
 Realizado Con Exito!');
} else {
    $respuesta = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al 
 registrar el pedido en la base de datos');
}
 } else {
$respuesta = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al enviar 
 el correo: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
 }

// Devolver respuesta al cliente (JavaScript)
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8mb4');
 echo json_encode($respuesta);
 


Hola, no se entiende tu pregunta. ¿De dónde sacas la variable $datos? Explica el contexto. Al parecer, al enviar un correo, haces una inserción en la base de datos. ¿Qué quieres a partir de ahí?

No marcaste tu ultima pregunta como resuelta, aun cuando dijiste que lo habías resuelto con la respuesta. Yo te podría indicar como proceder pero debes seguir las normas o costumbres de SOes

Si tienes razon olvide marcarla, ya lo hice disculpa por eso.... soy nuevo en el foro. @OCHOA

Voy arreglar mejor el codigo es que el foro me dice que esta muy largo y no me deja publicar todo dejame agregarlo por partes @A.Cedano

Listo @A.Cedano ya modifique el codigo hasta donde me dejo el foro... por que no me deja agregar todo el codigo en la pregunta.

Esta respuesta es similar a la ultima que te hice, es decir, no voy a usar tu código al 100% sino que te daré la lógica de como se hace.
Todo está en hacer las cosas en el orden preciso.
Para obtener el ID del registro insertado necesitas la función mysqli_insert_id que hace justo lo que necesitas.
Entonces, en el insert haces algo como:
$query = "INSERT INTO pedidos (fecha, nombre, correo, telefono, 
 total, productos,tipoentrega, direccionentrega) VALUES ('$fecha', 
'$nombre', '$correo', '$telefono', '$total', '$productos', 
'$tipoentrega', '$direccionentrega')";

// Ejecutar la consulta SQL
if (mysqli_query($conexion, $query)) {
    $lastID = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
    $respuesta = array('success' => true, 'message' => '¡Pedido 
 Realizado Con Exito!');
}

Y listo, ya tienes el ID insertado en la variable $lastID y puedes usarla donde quieras y como quieras.
 $mensaje = "
    <html>
     <head>
    <charset=utf-8>
    <title>Pedido de productos</title>
    <body>
    <h2>Detalle del pedido (LISTA)</h2><br>

     <p><strong>ID del pedido:</strong> " . $lastID . "</p> <===========

    <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> " . $datos['nombre'] . "</p>
    <p><strong>Correo electrónico:</strong> " . $datos['correo'] . " 
     </p>
    <p><strong>Teléfono:</strong> " . $datos['telefono'] . "</p>
    <p><strong>Opción de entrega:</strong> " . $datos['tipoentrega'] . 
  "</p>
    <p><strong>Dirección de entrega:</strong> " . 
    $datos['direccionentrega'] . "</p>  

